# Custom Vagrant SSH in Windows

Tags: ssh, vagrant, putty

I am trying to setup a new linux project using vagrant. I want to be able to ssh into the vagrant box with putty because it has copy paste capabilities. This is what I have done so far:

Navigated to the projects destination
In the command prompt typed

> vagrant init

I changed the following in the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.box = "base"
```

to

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
```

I then added the following lines into the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.12"
config.ssh.username = "test"
config.ssh.password = "password"
```

I saved the Vagrantfile

Then in the command prompt I typed

> vagrant up

This what comes up in the command prompt:

```
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/xenial64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/xenial64' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/xenial64' is available! You currently
==> default: have version '20170822.0.0'. The latest is version '20170919.0.0'. Run
==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: geoserver_default_1505948268591_35426
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2201.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2201 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2201
    default: SSH username: test
    default: SSH auth method: password
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
test@127.0.0.1's password:password
test@127.0.0.1's password:password
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
test@127.0.0.1's password:
test@127.0.0.1's password:
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
test@127.0.0.1's password:vagrant
test@127.0.0.1's password:vagrant
```

... I want a few minutes

```
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
test@127.0.0.1's password:    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
test@127.0.0.1's password:Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

I try and connect to the machine through putty with the following setting and I get a Network error: Connection timed out:

> Host Name: 192.168.10.12
>
> Port 2201
>
> Connection Type: SSH

I try and connect to the machine through putty with the following setting and I get connect to the machine but I am prompted for a username and password:

> Host Name: 127.0.0.1
>
> Port 2201
>
> Connection Type: SSH

The username/password combination I try is:

```
login as: test
password: password
```

I get an Access denied

```
login as: ubuntu
password: vagrant
```

I get an Access denied

How do I setup vagrant so that I can ssh in with putty?

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no test user in the VM so you cannot login with this user, you would first have to create a test user account with the password and then you will be able to connect.

The ubuntu password for this box is `95bf98670a543bcd7bdd576c`. You will find this information in the box's Vagrantfile, on Mac its located under `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-xenial64/20170116.1.0/virtualbox/Vagrantfile`

You can just remove username/password information from your Vagrantfile and you will login automatically when running `vagrant ssh`